# How to pass multiple parameters to url using angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am a newbie to angular js .
Here in my project i want to pass multiple parameters in anchor tag .
So that i will get multiple params in address bar too.
I have tried this one but its not working at all.

```html
 <a href="" ui-sref="edit_user({id:0,pid:'add-user'})">Add New user</a>
```

It is showing "http://localhost/Angular/#/edit-user/0",but i need to pass some more parameters.
Above is the code.
I want the url to be ""http://localhost/Angular/#/edit-user/0/add-user","
Here , am I doing anything wrong ?
Please suggest me .
Thank you.

Comment: could you please add `edit_user` state & please update your question with what additional parameter you wanted to set in `edit-user` page

Comment: These parameters must be also declared in ui-route config

Comment: see this. http://plnkr.co/edit/r2JhV4PcYpKJdBCwHIWS?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like :

```
$state.go('editUser', {id: 0, pid: 0});

 // or  In your view :

 <a ui-sref="editUser({id:0,pid:0})">Add New user</a>
```

In your config :

```
$stateProvider
.state('editUser', {
  url: '/edit-user?id&pid',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'users.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'

    },
  },
  params: {
    id: null,
    pid: null
  }
})
```